# How to write a condition when an option is selected from Checked Multi Select ("dojox.form.CheckedMultiSelect") in Dojo?

Tags: javascript, dojo

I need to write code to do something to a list depending on the options chosen from Checked Multi Select ("dojox.form.CheckedMultiSelect") in Dojo. How to write a condition when an option (or multiple options) is chosen in dojo?

```
<select multiple="true" name="multiselect" data-dojo-type="dojox.form.CheckedMultiSelect" data-dojo- 
 attach-point="mslt" dropDown="true"> 
    <option value="one" selected="selected" data-dojo-attach-point="chkWQT">Option-1</option>
    <option value="two" selected="selected" data-dojo-attach-point="chkWQL">Option-2</option>
</select>
```

Javascript:

```
if (//Option-1 is selected) {
  layerList.push.apply(List, Resources_GRP);
```

}

Answer (score 0):

```
var opt = this.mslt.getOptions();
if (opt[1].selected) {
    //Statement
}
```